# Correct information not being displayed in modal by using angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

When I click on the thumbnail image in the media object, for the race "Australian GP", the modal with its information is opened. But when I click on the thumbnail object for the race "Chinese GP", the modal still shows the information about the Australian GP rather than showing that of the Chinese GP. Where am I going wrong or what more do I have to add? And more importantly, can someone explain to me why my code is not working?

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="seasonCtrl">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="race in races">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="media first-media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ausmod"><img src="{{race.image}}" class="img-thumbnail media-object"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ausmod">{{race.name}}</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="label label-pill label-success">{{race.p1}}</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="label label-pill label-primary">{{race.p2}}</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="label label-info label-pill">{{race.p3}}</label></h2>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ausmod"><p>{{race.smallinfo}}</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="ausmod" ng-repeat="race in races">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4>{{race.modalName}}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>{{race.modalDesc}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
var app=angular.module("seasonApp", []);
        app.controller("seasonCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
            $scope.races=[
                {
                    image:"Aliens.jpg",
                    name:"Australian GP",
                    p1:"Nico Rosberg",
                    p2:"Lewis Hamilton",
                    p3:"Sebastian Vettel",
                    smallinfo:"wgliu uyrgf pw77t 2ieugt9weud w87e7t d",
                    modalName:"Australian GP 2016",
                    modalDesc:"test info for australia"
                },
                {
                    image:"daily_tasks.jpg",
                    name:"Chinese GP",
                    p1:"Nico Rosberg",
                    p2:"Sebastian Vettel",
                    p3:"Daniil Kvyat",
                    smallinfo:"wgliu uyrgf pw77t 2ieugt9weud w87e7t d",
                    modalName:"Chinese GP 2016",
                    modalDesc:"test info"
                }
            ];
        }]);
    </script>
```

Comment: Because id="used" repeated twice. id must be unique,be careful.
use such this data-target="#ausmod"+race and id="ausmod"+race ng-repeat="race in races">

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan how does adding +race help? I am not aware how it will work. Could you explain?

Comment: add into scop id (id:1,image:"Aliens.jpg" ... ) after try id="ausmod{{race.id}}"  or id="ausmod"{{race.id}}.
or if you dont wont adding id,can output what data you have (race.image)

Comment: like this  <div class="modal fade" id="ausmod{{race.image}}" ng-repeat="race in races">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create a scope variable that is set to the currently selected 'race' on the ng-click of your anchor tags and use that in your modal.

**Add to Controller**

```
$scope.selectedRace = {};

$scope.setSelectedRace = function(idx) {
  $scope.selectedRace = $scope.races[idx];
};
```

**HTML Changes**

Add 'track by $index' to assure unique rows

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="race in races" track by $index>
```

Add ng-click to each anchor

```
ng-click="setSelectedRace($index)"
```

Remove ng-repeat from modal div

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ausmod">
```

Change modal content to reference selectedRace object rather than race

```
<h4>{{selectedRace.modalName}}</h4>

<p>{{selectedRace.modalDesc}}</p>
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/JzYiOFRrk5mjGBqx645p?p=preview)

Comment: why remove ng-repeat from the modal div?

Comment: There's no need for it since you're only wanting the info for the selected race to show up in the modal.

Answer (score 1):

I have improved your code.It does not work because in the loop attribute id has to be unique.

Controllr

```
var app=angular.module("seasonApp", []);
app.controller("seasonCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.races=[
        {
            image:"Aliens.jpg",
            name:"Australian GP",
            p1:"Nico Rosberg",
            p2:"Lewis Hamilton",
            p3:"Sebastian Vettel",
            smallinfo:"wgliu uyrgf pw77t 2ieugt9weud w87e7t d",
            modalName:"Australian GP 2016",
            modalDesc:"test info for australia"
        },
        {
            image:"daily_tasks.jpg",
            name:"Chinese GP",
            p1:"Nico Rosberg",
            p2:"Sebastian Vettel",
            p3:"Daniil Kvyat",
            smallinfo:"wgliu uyrgf pw77t 2ieugt9weud w87e7t d",
            modalName:"Chinese GP 2016",
            modalDesc:"test info"
        }
    ];
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="seasonCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="race in races">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="media first-media" track by $index>
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ausmod{{$index}}">AAA</a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ausmod">{{race.name}}</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="label label-pill label-success">{{race.p1}}</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="label label-pill label-primary">{{race.p2}}</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="label label-info label-pill">{{race.p3}}</label></h2>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ausmod"><p>{{race.smallinfo}}</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="ausmod{{$index}}" ng-repeat="race in races" track by $index>
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4>{{race.modalName}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{race.modalDesc}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```